# VBA Script Renaming the files I copied over is not working

Tags: vba

I believe I'm on the right tract with the copying files and renaming, them, but my script is hanging with..."Run-Time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument."
... on the last line "ObjFso1.MoveFile SourceLocation & "" & SourceFileName, DestinationLocation & "" & DestinationFileName"
And, I'm not sure how to resolve it.

Code:

```
Sub moveTxt()
year_Month = Format(DateAdd("m", 1, Date), "yyyy mmm")
yearMonth = Format(DateAdd("m", 1, Date), "yyyymmm")
Yr = Format(Application.WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(Date, 1), "yyyy")
Mnth = Format(Application.WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(Date, 1), "mmm")
'
Dim ObjFso
Dim ObjFso1
Dim StrSourceLocation
Dim StrDestinationLocation
Dim SourceLocation
Dim DestinationLocation
Dim SourceFileName
Dim DestinationFileName
'
' Copying the *.txt files to the working directory
'
Dim StrSourceFileName
Dim StrDestinationFileName

StrSourceLocation = "\\san\PPC_VENDOR\"
StrDestinationLocation = "\\san\PPC\WORK BASKETS\Forms and Files\" & Yr & "\" & Yr & " " & Mnth & "\Vendor Recon Files\"    'All text files will be copied to destination
StrSourceFileName = "*.txt"                                                    'Creating the file system object
'
Set ObjFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")              'Copying the file
ObjFso.CopyFile StrSourceLocation & "" & StrSourceFileName, StrDestinationLocation & "", True
'
' Renaming the *.txt files
'
SourceLocation = "\\san\PPC\WORK BASKETS\Forms and Files\" & Yr & "\" & Yr & " " & Mnth & "\Vendor Recon Files\"
DestinationLocation = "\\san\PPC\WORK BASKETS\Forms and Files\" & Yr & "\" & Yr & " " & Mnth & "\Vendor Recon Files\"
SourceFileName = "BC*.txt"
DestinationFileName = "vendor_ins_" & yearMonth & "_v56_*.txt"  'Creating the file system object
SourceFileName = "BS*.txt"
DestinationFileName = "vendor_ins_" & yearMonth & "_v55_*.txt"  'Creating the file system object
SourceFileName = "DD*.txt"
DestinationFileName = "vendor_ins_" & yearMonth & "_v57_*.txt"  'Creating the file system object
SourceFileName = "NC*.txt"
DestinationFileName = "vendor_ins_" & yearMonth & "_v54_*.txt"  'Creating the file system object
'
Set ObjFso1 = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")             'Moving the file
ObjFso1.MoveFile SourceLocation & "" & SourceFileName, DestinationLocation & "" & DestinationFileName
```

End Sub

Do you have any ideas?
JD

Answer (score 0):

You redefine the SourceFileName and DestinationFileName 4 times.  Each one is not unique.  You would have to use a `Select Case` or `If Then` statement to define each one depending on a given condition.  Or you would have to have your `MoveFile` code in between each variable definition.

Edit:  Also try

```
Dim SourcePath As String
Dim DestPath As String
SourcePath = SourceDestination & SourceFileName
DestPath = DestinationLocation & DestinationFileName
ObjFso1.MoveFile Source:=SourcePath, Destination:=DestPath
```

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes to the code because the above script did not accomplish what I wanted. Please tell me what I need to change in this new script...

```
Sub moveTxt()
year_Month = Format(DateAdd("m", 1, Date), "yyyy mmm")
yearMonth = Format(DateAdd("m", 1, Date), "yyyymmm")
Yr = Format(Application.WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(Date, 1), "yyyy")
Mnth = Format(Application.WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(Date, 1), "mmm")
'
Dim ObjFso
Dim SourcePath As String
Dim DestPath As String
Set ObjFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'
SourceLocation = "\\san\PPC_VENDOR\"
DestinationLocation = "\\san\PPC\WORK BASKETS\Forms and Files\" & Yr & "\" & Yr & " " & Mnth & "\Vendor Recon Files\"
SourcePath = SourceLocation & SourceFileName
DestPath = DestinationLocation & DestinationFileName
'
SourceFileName = "BC*.txt"
DestinationFileName = "vendor_ins_" & yearMonth & "_v56.txt"
ObjFso.MoveFile Source:=SourcePath, Destination:=DestPath
'
SourceFileName = "BS*.txt"
DestinationFileName = "vendor_ins_" & yearMonth & "_v55.txt"
ObjFso.MoveFile Source:=SourcePath, Destination:=DestPath
'
SourceFileName = "DD*.txt"
DestinationFileName = "vendor_ins_" & yearMonth & "_v57.txt"
ObjFso.MoveFile Source:=SourcePath, Destination:=DestPath
'
SourceFileName = "NC*.txt"
DestinationFileName = "vendor_ins_" & yearMonth & "_v54.txt"
ObjFso.MoveFile Source:=SourcePath, Destination:=DestPath
```

End Sub

This code stops on Line: 19 with "Run-time error '53': File not found".

Thank you for any ideas would be appreciated,
JD